# Are retracts always closed in a compact weak Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

A retract is a subspace $R\subseteq X$ for which there exists a continuous map $f:X\to R$ with $f(r)=r$ for all $r\in R$.

If $X$ is compact and has the property [KC](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000100) (all compacts are closed, a weakening of $T_2$), then every retract is compact and therefore closed.

Can KC be weakened to [weakly Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000143) here? Note that the [one-point compactification of the Arens square space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000165) shows that KC cannot be weakened as far as [US](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000099).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [square of the one-point compactification of the rationals](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000031) is compact and weakly Hausdroff, but its diagonal is a retract (by $(p,q)\mapsto(q,q)$) that is not closed in the space.

More generally, the square of any compact, weakly Hausdorff, non-$T_2$ space is compact and weakly Hausdorff, but has a non-closed diagonal which is a compact retract.